# Hypothesis test for Bernoulli

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, statistical-significance, bernoulli-distribution

Let $X_{1},..,X_{36}$ be a sample from a Bernoulli distribution with parameter $p$. The sample proportion is $\frac{1}{3}$. Consider a normal approximation test $H_{0}:p=0.5$ vs $H_{1}:p\neq 0.5$, with confidence level $0.95$.
How will the criterion change if $H_{1}$ is replaced by $p=1/3$?

Comment: How do is it possible that Bernoulli deviates have a mean of 12?

Comment: This question seems to be a [self-study](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) question. Please add the `self-study` tag if appropriate.

Comment: My guess is that the mean is $1/2$.

Comment: @Matt no the sample *proportion* is 1/3, the question originally said "mean of 12" but the OP meant to write 12 successes e.g. $\hat{p} = 1/3$.

Comment: @QuantIbex i know how to do simple hypothesis tests with neyman pearson lemma. What are the instructions for this type of hypotheis test?

Answer (score 1):

First hint is to write the variance of a single Bernoulli random variable. The second hint is to apply the Central Limit Theorem and calculate the normal approximation to the variance of the sample proportion for $n=36$. The third and final hint is to construct the usual test-statistic for inference and compare its distribution to a normal density.

Comment: Variance is $p(1-p)$. The CLT says that $\frac{X_{1}+..+X_{36}}{36}$ is approximately $N(p,p(1-p))$. How to construct the statistic?

Comment: Be careful when you write $p$, these is no $p$, there is $p_0$ and $\hat{p}$.

Comment: ok, what now then?

Comment: Your normal approximation is wrong.

Comment: There are three types of (asymptotic) test statistics you can write. The two most obvious are the Wald and the Score statistics (3rd is likelihood ratio). The Score statistics calculates the variance of the test statistic *under the null hypothesis*. So you will use $\sqrt{p_0(1-p_0)/n}$ as an *estimate* of the standard error of the mean.

Comment: Then $\dfrac{\hat{p} - p_0}{\sqrt{p_0(1-p_0)/n}}$ has an asymptotically $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ distribution. So compare this $\mathcal{Z}$ value to the standard normal density curve.

Comment: oh sorry I didn't know there were others, I'm meant to be using likelihood ratios. Also, what it $p_{0}$?

Comment: $p_0$ is the restricted maximum likelihood estimate of $p$... which is the unknown parameter of interest. The null hypothesis has restrictions about what it can be... hint it's just one point.

Comment: I get that the test statistic is 2>1.96 so reject $H_{0}$. Correct? Thanks